# DialogResult::OK doesn't work

Tags: .net, winforms, c++-cli

I faced a mistake in the code below:

```
if (folderBrowserDialog1->ShowDialog() == DialogResult::OK )
      {

      }
```

The mistake is in `DialogResult::OK` ! The compiler says `error C2065: 'OK' : undeclared identifier`
?
I already did `using namespace System::IO;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DialogResult` doesn't seem to be in the `System::IO` namespace--were you looking for the one under `System::Windows::Forms`?  When in doubt, search MSDN.

Answer (score 2):

[DialogResult for winforms is in the System.Windows.Forms assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dialogresult.aspx)